# Which algorithm do I need for this directed graph operation?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, digraphs

I may be overthinking this and be missing something obvious, but I was wondering which NetworkX algorithm I could use to achieve the following:

Given a DiGraph such as:

[image: Simple DiGraph]

And a list of nodes such as: Q1, Q2

Find all nodes which are connected to (or in other words children of) Q1 and Q2, the results would be as following:

[image: Q1]

[image: Q2]

Which algorithm would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to make a recursion over [networkx.Digraph.predecessors](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html)

Answer (score 0):

A first way is to use a list, visit the predecessor of each node starting from your node and put it in the list, building in this way a tree with the nodes you find.

Another way is to use a  visit (DFS or BFS) on the graph reversing the edges.

Consider the following example where I build a [bfs tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree.html) starting at Node "Q1".

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()

g.add_edges_from([("M1","Q1"),("I1","M1"),("I2","M1"),("I3","M1"),("I3","M2"),("M2","Q2")])

#creating a graph with the edges reversed
g2 = nx.DiGraph()
g2.add_edges_from([(v,u) for (u,v) in g.edges()])

t = nx.bfs_tree(g2, "Q1")

for (u,v) in t.edges():
    t.remove_edge(u,v)
    t.add_edge(v,u)


print(t.nodes(),t.edges())
# ['Q1', 'M1', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3'] [('M1', 'Q1'), ('I1', 'M1'), ('I2', 'M1'), ('I3', 'M1')]
```